# Piping a readstream into a writestream does not work

Tags: node.js, stream, restify

I (as the client) am trying to post an image with restify, and the server just needs to save it.

```
req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.jpg'));
```

is not working. An empty file is created but nothing more. It works when I copy `req.body` into a buffer and then `fs.writeFile(...)`. I have also tried `req.body.pipe`, but this throws an error.

Comment: Just wondering, is this for gridfs?

Also, are you listening for the [finish](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.36/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event on the writeStream? You have to make sure that all of the data passes through the stream before sending a response.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a body parser middleware that is already reading all of the data from the request so there is nothing left to read. Try adjusting the placement of your route handler and/or body parsing middleware if you want to read directly from the request object.

However, that will only work if the request contains *only* the image data. Typically a request is formatted as `multipart/form-data` if it contains at least one file, so you cannot just pipe the request and expect image data only.

Answer (score 0):

So something else in your middleware chain, probably `restify.bodyParser()`, is already streaming the request body into a buffer or string as `req.body` and you can't stream something twice. Find the middleware and disable it for this route if you want to handle the streaming straight to the filesystem yourself.